# use stream to sum all values from array stored in map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map which looks like this:

```
Map<String,String[]> urlFormEncoded = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
```

and I would like to sum all values stored in String[] arrays as a double value
I tried something like this:

```
double requestAmount = urlFormEncoded.entrySet().stream().mapToDouble(k -> Arrays.stream(k.getValue()).).sum();
```

but unfortunately I don't know how to convert this String[] to value :(
I would like to do this using streams and lambda expressions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first step would be to convert each `String[]` as a `DoubleStream`.

```
Arrays.stream(arr).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf)
```

Then you have to `flatMap` those streams to get a single `DoubleStream` will all the `double` values.

```
.flatMapToDouble(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf))
```

So you end up with:

```
double requestAmount = 
    urlFormEncoded.values()
                  .stream()
                  .flatMapToDouble(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf))
                  .sum();
```

Note that you don't need to use the `entrySet()` if you plan to work only on the values, you can directly use `values()`.