# Compute the Mean of a List<Double> in a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, math, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Given a map from Names to lists of Numbers.

I'd like to compute the mean for each Name using the java 8 stream api.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> NameToQuaters = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Double> NameToMean = ?
```

Comment: Quasi-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559046/use-stream-to-sum-all-values-from-array-stored-in-map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
Map<String, Double> nameToMean = nameToQuaters.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // the key is the same
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                // for the value of the key, you can calculate the average like so
                e -> e.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble())
        );
    }
```

Or you can create a method which make the average and return it back for example :

```
public Double average(List<Double> values) {
    return values.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble();
}
```

then your code can be :

```
Map<String, Double> nameToMean = nameToQuaters.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> average(e.getValue())) );
```

Comment: The question is not about the sum, but the mean. Collecting the mean from a DoubleStream is easy, but if you're going to provide an answer, you might as well go the final mile :-)

Comment: @GPI sorry I don't understand the question correct until I use google [translate](https://translate.google.dz/?hl=fr&tab=wT#en/fr/compute%20th%C3%A9%20mean%20f%C3%B6r%20each) I get it now, the OP need the average right? check my answer as well now!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Map<String, List<Double>> nameToQuaters = new HashMap<>();
//fill source map
Map<String, Double> nameToMean = new HashMap<>();
nameToQuaters.
    .forEach((key, value) -> nameToMean.put(key, value.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).average().getAsDouble()));
```

Comment: Aside from not using stream, this is a concise solution. You can make it even nicer to read by using `Map.forEach()` instead of `Map.entrySet().forEach()`. This makes the `entry.get...` unnecessary.

Comment: Thx to You to @Lorelorelore .
" value.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).average().getAsDouble() " will come in handy in another place